# python - why is read-only property writable?

Tags: python, properties, python-2.7, readonly, private-members

I am trying to define a class with a read-only property in a Python; I followed Python documentation and came up with the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class Test:
        def __init__(self, init_str):
                self._prop = init_str

        @property
        def prop(self):
                return self._prop

t = Test("Init")
print t.prop
t.prop = "Re-Init"
print t.prop
```

Now when I try to execute the code though I am expecting error/exception I see it getting executed normally:

```
$ ./python_prop_test 
Init
Re-Init
```

My Python version is 2.7.2. What I am seeing, is it expected? How do make sure a property is not settable?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For this to work as you expect, `Test` needs to be a new-style class:

```
class Test(object):
          ^^^^^^^^
```

This is hinted at in the [documentation for `property()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#property):

> Return a property attribute for *new-style classes* (classes that derive from `object`).

When I turn `Test` into a new-style class, and attempt to change `prop`, I get an exception:

```
In [28]: t.prop='Re-Init'

AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

Comment: The old-style class doesn't give priority to the `property` data descriptor; it lets you shadow the attribute in the instance dict.

Answer (score 4):

To use properties you must use new-style classes.  To use new-style classes in Python 2 you must inherit from `object`.  Change your class def to `class Test(object)`.

Comment: In my case It didn't work without `object` even for Python 3