# How can I make a read-only property mutable?

Tags: python, python-2.7, properties, new-style-class, augmented-assignment

I have two classes, one with an "in-place operator" override (say `+=`) and another that exposes an instance of the first through a `@property`.  (Note:  this is *greatly* simplified from my actual code to the minimum that reproduces the problem.)

```
class MyValue(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        self.value += other
        return self

    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.value)

class MyOwner(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._what = MyValue(40)

    @property
    def what(self):
        return self._what
```

Now, when I try to use that operator on the exposed property:

```
>>> owner = MyOwner()
>>> owner.what += 2
AttributeError: can't set attribute
```

From what I've found this is to be expected, since it's trying to set the property on `owner`.  **Is there some way to prevent *setting* the property to a new object, while still allowing me to (in-place) *modify* the object behind it, or is this just a quirk of the language?**

(See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15458613/python-why-is-read-only-property-writable), but I'm trying to go the other way, preferably *without* reverting to old-style classes because eventually I want it to work with Python 3.)

---

In the meantime I've worked around this with a method that does the same thing.

```
class MyValue(object):
    # ... 

    def add(self, other):
        self.value += other

>>> owner = MyOwner()
>>> owner.what.add(2)
>>> print(owner.what)
42
```

Comment: Other workarounds: `temp = owner.what; temp += 2`, `[owner.what][0] += 2`.

Comment: I'd like to keep the "hackish" parts out of the user code, so I'm going with @Martijn's answer, but thanks for the ideas; they may come in handy for other things.  I do like that they're very concise (especially the second :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a quirk of the language; the `object += value` operation translates to:

```
object = object.__iadd__(value)
```

This is necessary because not all objects are mutable. Yours is, and correctly returns `self` resulting in a virtual no-op for the assignment part of the above operation.

In your case, the `object` in question is also an attribute, so the following is executed:

```
owner.what = owner.what.__iadd__(2)
```

Apart from avoiding referencing `object.what` here on the left-hand side (like `tmp = owner.what; tmp += 2`), there is a way to handle this cleanly.

You can easily detect that the assignment to the property concerns the *same object* and gate on that:

```
class MyOwner(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._what = MyValue(40)

    @property
    def what(self):
        return self._what

    @what.setter
    def what(self, newwhat):
        if newwhat is not self._what:
            raise AttributeError("can't set attribute")
        # ignore the remainder; the object is still the same
        # object *anyway*, so no actual assignment is needed
```

Demo:

```
>>> owner = MyOwner()
>>> owner.what
40
>>> owner.what = 42
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 24, in what
AttributeError: can't set attribute
>>> owner.what += 2
>>> owner.what
42
```

Comment: "This is a quirk of the language."  I was afraid of that.  I'll try your suggestion, thanks.